# How do I exclude weekends in SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime, date-arithmetic

I have a date column `SLA_Date` in the `Orders` table.

My `SLA_Date` should exclude weekends (Saturday & Sunday). Data for weekdays should be shown alone.

How do I do that in SQL?

Comment: Are you inserting to the table? querying it? What are you trying to do exactly?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You just need to add the following **filter**:

```
WHERE TO_CHAR(date_column, 'DY','NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=AMERICAN') NOT IN ('SAT', 'SUN')
```

Your query would look like:

```
SELECT SLA_Date
   FROM orders
 WHERE TO_CHAR(SLA_Date, 'DY','NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=AMERICAN') NOT IN ('SAT', 'SUN')
```

For example(the WITH clause is only to build a test case), the below query is to display only the weekdays(i.e. excluding the Sat and Sun) ranging from `1st May 2015` to `31st May 2015`:

```
SQL> WITH DATA AS
  2    (SELECT to_date('05/01/2015', 'MM/DD/YYYY') date1,
  3      to_date('05/31/2015', 'MM/DD/YYYY') date2
  4    FROM dual
  5    )
  6  SELECT date1+LEVEL-1 the_date,
  7        TO_CHAR(date1+LEVEL-1, 'DY','NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=AMERICAN') day
  8  FROM DATA
  9  WHERE TO_CHAR(date1+LEVEL-1, 'DY','NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=AMERICAN')
 10        NOT IN ('SAT', 'SUN')
 11  CONNECT BY LEVEL <= date2-date1+1;

THE_DATE  DAY
--------- ---
01-MAY-15 FRI
04-MAY-15 MON
05-MAY-15 TUE
06-MAY-15 WED
07-MAY-15 THU
08-MAY-15 FRI
11-MAY-15 MON
12-MAY-15 TUE
13-MAY-15 WED
14-MAY-15 THU
15-MAY-15 FRI
18-MAY-15 MON
19-MAY-15 TUE
20-MAY-15 WED
21-MAY-15 THU
22-MAY-15 FRI
25-MAY-15 MON
26-MAY-15 TUE
27-MAY-15 WED
28-MAY-15 THU
29-MAY-15 FRI

21 rows selected.

SQL>
```

For a detailed example, see [Generate Date, Month Name, Week Number, Day number between two dates](http://lalitkumarb.wordpress.com/2015/04/15/generate-date-month-name-week-number-day-number-between-two-dates-in-oracle-sql/)

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following condition to filter your data:

```
WHERE to_char (SLA_Date, 'FmDay', 'nls_date_language=english') <> 'Saturday'
  AND to_char (SLA_Date, 'FmDay', 'nls_date_language=english') <> 'Sunday'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select *
from   orders
where  TRUNC (thing) - TRUNC (thing, 'IW') between 0 and 4;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/db891/1