# How to project installments based on daily balances in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, date-arithmetic

I have a table with the following simplfied structure:
balance,date,credit_type.
Based on the date and credit type (daily loads) I need to project the future flows for my balances.
Also need to consider weekends and holidays, 
Any ideas?

Here is some example data:

```
data table          
balance_actual  partner credit_type date
12000            C&A    CRD_type_1  25-08-2015

Rule Table          
credit_type No_Of_Installments  days_due_1st_Installment next_install_days 
 CRD_type_1           2               3                          4
```

Here is the desired Result Set:

```
balance_forecast    partner credit_type date
6000                 C&A    CRD_type_1  26-08-2015
6000                 C&A    CRD_type_1  27-08-2015
0                    C&A    CRD_type_1  28-08-2015
6000                 C&A    CRD_type_1  29-08-2015
6000                 C&A    CRD_type_1  30-08-2015
6000                 C&A    CRD_type_1  31-08-2015
0                    C&A    CRD_type_1  01-09-2015
```

The desired balance_forecast = balance_actual / No_Of_Installments.
On day 28-08-2015 my balance_forecast is zero , because days_due_1st_Installment= 3 (3 days after initial date). Same for date 01-09-2015 zeros again, because next_install_day = 4 (4 days after the first installment date).

Comment: I assume this makes sense to you because you know exactly what business logic you want to apply and exactly what output you'd want.  The rest of us aren't you, however.  We don't know your system.  We don't know your data.  We don't know your requirements.  You'll have to show us what results you want.  That probably requires that you show us some sample data, tell us exactly what output you'd want with that data and explain why.  For example, it may be obvious to you what "consider weekends and holidays" means but I have no idea what that means.

Comment: Justin, ok fair enough. I need to find a way to forecast for future dates based on my two tables, the flows from my credit balances based on the number of installments and first due days. i will pot an example on a spredsheet.

Comment: Can you include whatever information we would need to help you in the question itself rather than in external links.

Comment: it wont let me inlcude gifs, just click on the link ...

Comment: The link doesn't work for me.  It probably won't work for most people behind corporate firewalls.  Links to external resources that form the entire basis of a question also tend to disappear over time leaving the question unusable for others.  That's why SO requires that the question have all the information needed to answer in the question itself.

Answer (score 0):

There are several small problems to solve.

1. Calculate the due date and size of each installment
2. Calculate the budget forecast
3. Generate a matrix of dates spanning the life of the loan

There are a couple of ways of solving them.  The MODEL clause is one option, but that's pretty gnarly.  Using a series of sub-queries is more verbose but makes it easier to see what's going on.

The first sub-query joins the LOAN details with its RULE and also calculates the life of the loan and the size of each installment.

```
with lr as  ( select l.balance_actual
       , l.start_date
       , l.partner
       , l.credit_type
       , r.days_due_1st_Installment 
                  + (r.next_install_days * (r.No_Of_Installments-1)) tot_days
       , (l.balance_actual/r.No_Of_Installments) installment
       , r.days_due_1st_Installment
       , r.next_install_days
       , r.No_Of_Installments
from loan l
     join rule r
          on l.credit_type = r.credit_type
```

)

The second sub-query takes that output and calculates the date when each loan is due, using the CONNECT BY trick to spawn a set of rows:

```
 , sch as (
    select case when level = 1 then lr.start_date + lr.days_due_1st_Installment
                  else lr.start_date + lr.days_due_1st_Installment
                               + (lr.next_install_days * (level-1))
             end as due_date
           , lr.*
    from lr
    connect by level <= lr.No_Of_Installments 
    )
```

A third sub-query generates a list of dates, again using the CONNECT BY trick:

```
 , pln as ( select lr.start_date + level as cal_date
            from lr
            connect by level <= lr.tot_days 
     )
```

The main query joins these sub-queries using an exciting array of join types, and employs an Analytic SUM() function to calculate the remaining balance:

```
select pln.cal_date
       , sch.installment as install_due
       , lr.balance_actual - nvl((sum(sch.installment) 
                         over (order by pln.cal_date)),0) as forecast_balance
       , lr.credit_type
       , lr.partner
from lr 
     cross join pln
     left join sch on sch.due_date =  pln.cal_date
order by pln.cal_date
;
```

Note that my calculation of FORECAST_BUDGET differs from the posted one.  I think my implementation makes more sense but the OP may disagree :)

So, here is the whole thing:

```
with lr as 
  ( select l.balance_actual
           , l.start_date
           , l.partner
           , l.credit_type
           , r.days_due_1st_Installment + (r.next_install_days * (r.No_Of_Installments-1)) tot_days
           , (l.balance_actual/r.No_Of_Installments) installment
           , r.days_due_1st_Installment
           , r.next_install_days
           , r.No_Of_Installments
    from loan l
         join rule r
              on l.credit_type = r.credit_type
   )
 , sch as (
    select case when level = 1 then lr.start_date + lr.days_due_1st_Installment
                  else lr.start_date + lr.days_due_1st_Installment + (lr.next_install_days * (level-1))
             end as due_date
            , lr.*
    from lr
    connect by level <= lr.No_Of_Installments 
    )
 , pln as ( select lr.start_date + level as cal_date
            from lr
            connect by level <= lr.tot_days 
     )
select pln.cal_date
       , sch.installment as install_due
       , lr.balance_actual - nvl((sum(sch.installment) over (order by pln.cal_date)),0) as forecast_balance
       , lr.credit_type
       , lr.partner
from lr 
     cross join pln
     left join sch on sch.due_date =  pln.cal_date
order by pln.cal_date
```

There is also [a SQL Fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9e1643/3).

---

Neither of the date calculations take into account holidays or weekends.  That's because the Seeker didn't specify want they wanted, although we can guess (i.e. instalment periods and due dates are working days only).

Oracle does not provide a built-in solution for holidays.  Consequently applications must handle them in their own way.

Weekends are problematic because they are defined by NLS parameters (is Sunday day 1 or day 7 of your week?  Which days comprise the weekend?).  [Other SO threads tackle this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30617282/how-do-i-exclude-weekends-in-sql).

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. I tried inserting two different dates on my loan table and hada some unexpected results. Would like to be able to forecast several dates at once also on my result table would like to have a column transaction-date = start-date.

Comment: APC , the query is running ok with only one record in the Loan table. When I add two more records and adjust the no.of installments in 24 and days_due to 30 it freezes!

Comment: I have already put quite a lot of work into this answer.  If you still have issues with it then you must give specifics.  I am not prepared to waste my time second-guessing you.  So, please, *edit your question* with this new data.  You might also want to include that `transaction-date` column.  Incidentally the `LOAN` table lacks an ID.  I presume that was for simplicity.  However, working with multiples demands a mechanism for identifying each Loan.  Remember to include one.